# c++ how to copy range from vector using two iterators

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, copy

I have this example code that doesn't compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::endl; using std::cin; using std::cout;
using std::vector;


int main()
{
    vector<int> vi, seg;
    vi.push_back(3);
    vi.push_back(4);
    vi.push_back(5);
    vi.push_back(6);
    vi.push_back(7);
    vector<int>::const_iterator ci_start = vi.begin();
    vector<int>::const_iterator ci_actual = vi.begin();
    while (ci_actual != vi.end())
    {   
        seg = vi(ci_start, ci_actual);
        cout << "......" ;
        for (const vector<int>::const_iterator ci = vi.begin();
                                    ci != vi.end(); ++ci)
            cout << *ci << " ";
        cout << endl;

        ++ci_actual;
    }   
}
```

What I want is to pass increasing parts of vector `vi` (that is going to take some million elements) to a function (not shown).  These segments are considered from the begining of `vi` up to where `actual` is at the moment.
For this, I've declared `seg` that was supposed to have part of vi.

Desired output would be:

3
3  4
3  4  5
3  4  5  6
3  4  5  6  7

Is `seg` not supposed to hold a copy of elements of `vi` denoted by iterators `ci_start` and `ci_actual`?

To pass the ever increasing part of `vi` to the function I refered (absent), can I do it faster without copying the elements of `vi` to another vector and just pass a reference to a segment of `vi`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> vi;

    vi.push_back(3);
    vi.push_back(4);
    vi.push_back(5);
    vi.push_back(6);
    vi.push_back(7);

    //the end of the sequence 
    vector<int>::iterator seq_end = vi.begin() + 1;

    while (seq_end != vi.end())
    {
        cout << "......" ;
        for (vector<int>::iterator ci = vi.begin(); ci != seq_end; ++ci)
            cout << *ci << " ";
        cout << endl;

        any_function(vi.begin(), seq_end);

        ++seq_end;
    }   
}

void any_function(const vector<int>::iterator& seq_start,
                  const vector<int>::iterator& seq_end)
{
    ...
}
```

this code make it, analyze and repair your mistakes.

Comment: Hi, what I asked was not exactly this.  Suppose vector `vi` has 10 million elements. As stated above, in each iteration of the while loop, I want to pass elements from `vi` as an argument. In 1st iteration: 1 element; in 2nd, two elements (1st e 2nd), and so forth. My question was: Do I really need to create vector seg for this? If so, I need to copy elements from `vi` to `seg` in each iteration which is expensive.  Or can I pass pointers to `vi` in order to avoid copying? Or another solution?

Comment: then you don't need seg, just send the vi as const reference

Answer (score 3):

```
for (const vector<int>::const_iterator ci = vi.begin(); ci != vi.end(); ++ci)
```

You are declaring a const const_interator here.  Meaning whey you try to call ++ci, the compiler will yell at you for trying to modify a constant variable.  This should fix that compiler error:

```
for (vector<int>::const_iterator ci = vi.begin(); ci != vi.end(); ++ci)
```

Comment: Well, there were two errors and you solved one. Thank you.  But I still get:ex.cpp:23: error: passing 'const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >' as 'this' argument of '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>& __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator++() [with _Iterator = const int*, _Container = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >]' discards qualifiers

Comment: That is likely due to your `seg = vi(ci_start, ci_actual);` line which @Lou pointed out below.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a compiler error, please tell us what it is.  It looks like this:

```
  seg = vi(ci_start, ci_actual);
```

Should be

```
  vector<int> seg(ci_start, ci_actual);
```

And remove the declaration of seg at the top of main().

And your for loop should use seg.begin()/seg.end() if you want to print the segment

Comment: After removing the `const` from the vector<int> declaration in the for cycle, I tryed again your suggestion and the compiler doesn't complain anymore.  It seems that there is no problem to keep re-declaring vector<int> seg inside the while loop.  Shouldn't the variable be declared only once?

Comment: It is only declared once.  The loop doesn't keep declaring it -- it keeps constructing it, but that's ok because you want a different seg for each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Re: your follow-on question about how to call a helper function that you want to operate on a subrange of your large vector...

First, [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110523/slicing-a-vector) might be useful.  The accepted "just pass a pair of iterators" answer was exactly what I was about to suggest.

Second, if you're OK using the boost libraries, the [vector proxy libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/vector_proxy.htm) may be useful.