# Remove first N elements from a std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I can't seem to think of a reliable way (that also compacts memory) to remove the first N elements from a `std::vector`. How would one go about doing that?

Comment: Would changing to a `std::deque` interest you? It's way more efficient for this.

Comment: Never mind! I am having a huge brain freeze today.

Comment: @Martinho No :-( Changing it to a deque is a laborious process now. I am wondering if I cannot use std::copy_backward somehow?

Comment: What's wrong with `v.erase(v.begin(),v.begin()+N)` ?

Comment: @Dilip? Laborious? How so? STL containers are easily swapped by just an single line change, *As long as you are using them correctly*, If you cannot probably you are not using them correctly?

Comment: @n.m. Nothing :-) I am still thawing out my brain

Comment: @Als -- its the size of the codebase. It involves modifying parts of code that I don't even own. Things are never so simple.

Comment: @Dilip : Sounds like someone didn't use `typedef` judiciously enough. ;-]

Comment: You can't typedef away that `std:vector<T>` is contiguous and `std::deque` isn't, which matters a lot when interfacing with legacy code that expects a T*. But for such code, you might be able to not delete the first N elements, and pass `&v[N]` instead.

Comment: @Als: Containers are not really that easily swappable. Each of them has very specific characteristics, so either some operations won't compile, or will compile but result in a signifant performance drop (e.g you replace vector with set, but happily keep using std::find). And as MSalters points out, replacing vector with deque may well result in undefined behavior.

Comment: The caveat "that also compacts memory" is going to be non-portable, because the standard never promises that you can.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Since you mention that you want to compact memory, it would be best to copy everything to a new vector and use the swap idiom.

```
std::vector<decltype(myvector)::value_type>(myvector.begin()+N, myvector.end()).swap(myvector);
```

Comment: Or more succinctly, `std::vector<myvector::value_type>(myvector.begin()+N, myvector.end()).swap(myvector);`.

Comment: @ildjarn, thank you - I knew there was a way to do it with an unnamed temporary but I had a brain freeze. I've updated my answer using your exact text.

Comment: @ild: Can you really use the `::` operator with non-types?

Comment: @FredOverflow, I think he copied that from me. I think you can, but I didn't test it.

Comment: @FredOverflow : Mark's correct, I copied it from him and didn't notice. Realistically it would of course be `myvector_t::value_type` or `decltype(myvector)::value_type`.

Comment: How about the memory allocated by the removed element in contrast to std::vector<>::erase ?

Comment: Sometimes a `std::decay_t` is needed. `std::vector<std::decay_t<decltype(myvector)>::value_type>(myvector.begin()+N, myvector.end()).swap(myvector);`

Answer (score 52):

Use the `.erase()` method:

```
// Remove the first N elements, and shift everything else down by N indices
myvec.erase(myvec.begin(), myvec.begin() + N);
```

This will require copying all of the elements from indices N+1 through the end.  If you have a large vector and will be doing this frequently, then use a `std::deque` instead, which has a more efficient implementation of removing elements from the front.

Comment: He also wants to compact the memory.

Comment: @Adam Thanks! I don't know how I missed a straight-forward thing like that. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Mooing I did mention that in my post but for now, that is less of a concern for me. This will get me going for the moment although I would love to know if there is a way I can compact the memory too.

Answer (score 13):

```
v.erase( v.begin(), v.size() > N ?  v.begin() + N : v.end() );
```

Don't forget the check of the size, just in case.

Comment: @Mooing Duck  I missed that.  In that case, he'll have to create a new vector: `std::vector<T>( v.begin() + std::min( N, v.size() ). v.end() )`