# What does 'compacting memory' mean when removing items from the front of a std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

[Remove first N elements from a std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351899/remove-first-n-elements-from-a-stdvector)

This question talks about removing items from a vector and 'compacting memory'.  What is 'compacting memory' and why is it important here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the implementation of the `std::vector` class is some code that dynamically allocates an array of data-elements.  Often not all of the elements in this internal array will be in use -- the array is often allocated to be bigger than what is currently needed, in order to avoid having to reallocate a bigger array too often (array-reallocations are expensive!).

Similarly, when items are removed from the `std::vector`, the internal data-array is not immediately reallocated to be smaller (because doing so would be expensive); rather, the now-extra slots in the array are left "empty" in the expectation that the calling code might want to re-use them in the near future.

However, those empty slots still take up RAM, so if the calling code has just removed a lot of items from the vector, it might want to force the vector to reallocate a smaller internal array that doesn't contain so many empty slots.  That is what they are referring to as `compacting` in that question.

Comment: Wouldn't reallocation when std::vector shrinks be just freeing memory at the end of the block? This should be faster than reallocating when std::vector size increases (= possibly allocating a larger block of memory, and then copying the content).

Comment: It might be faster than allocating a larger array (it depends on whether the underlying heap supports a partial-free operation).  In any case, accessing the heap is more expensive than not accessing the heap, so the vector class tries to avoid doing so when possible.

Answer (score 3):

The OP is talking about shrinking the memory the vector takes up.  When you erase elements from a vector its size decreases but it capacity (the memory it is using) remains the same.  When the OP says

> (that also compacts memory)

They want the removal of the elements to also shrink the capacity of the vector so it reduces its memory consumption.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the vector shouldn't use more memory than it needs to. In other words, the OP wants:

```
size() == capacity()
```

This can be achieved in C++11 and later by calling `shrink_to_fit()` on a vector. This is only a request though, it is not binding.

To make sure it will compact memory you should create a new vector and call `reserve(oldvector.size())`.

Comment: Ah - ok - so the linked question was quite old, and vec.erase(...) followed by shrink_to_fit() is probably a very appropriate approach now?

Comment: @JCX Correct yeah.

Comment: I'd not really appreciated that the vector never freed unused memory when stuff was deleted ...

Comment: @JCx use RAII for that.